# Excel search range of cells that contain text return entire cell that contains text

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a formula to check a set of data for a certain text. For example, assuming the below table starts in Cell A1, I would like to search Columns C,D,E,F,G for a string, and return the entire contents of the cell that contains that string. So for the "AltID 101020", I would like to search columns C-G for the string "Plan" and return the value of "Plan11" in B2, "Plan88" in B5, and "Plan2d" in B7.

```
       A         B       C      D       E       F       G       
     Data    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
    +--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
1   | AltID  |Plans  | CovA  | CovB  |CovC   | CovD  | CovE  |
    +--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
2   | 101020 |       | Pol3  |Plan11 |       |       |Coord2e|
3   | 907030 |       | Pol   |       | Sub5a | Alt24 |       |
4   | 805050 |       |       |       |       |       |       |
5   | 778050 |       |       |Plan88 | Sub7d |       |Coord2 |
6   | 232520 |       |       |       |       |       |       |
7   | 357031 |       |       |Plan2d | Sub7e |       |       |
8   | ...    |  ...  | ...   | ...   | ...   | ...   | ...   |
    +--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Will there only be a maximum of one column with the string "plan" or could there be several?

Comment: Eventually I would need to search strings "Pol", "Sub", "Alt", and "Coord" respectively. Each one with their own Column. But to keep it simple, I am starting with "Plan".

Comment: That still doesn't anser the question of a given string appearing at most a once or multiple times.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't (and maybe still don't) understand your question. Each column represents a category. Column C assumes cells will always contain data starting with "pol" or else it will be blank. Column D assumes cells will always contain data starting with "plan" or else it will be blank. And so on.

Comment: Jeeped: thank you for the formatting help. I tried to format it...and failed.

Comment: This is a growing spreadsheet, so there could be additional data and additional columns for which strings "Plan", "Sub","Alt", and "Coord" could be added. However for each altID, there will only be one instance of that data in the columns C,D,E,F,G,etc: meaning no AltID will have more than one  "Plan","Sub","Alt", or "Coord".

Answer (score 0):

Using this formula, you can see if there is the word "plan" in a cell or not. In case not there is an empty string. You can concatenate all those in one cell, and use a MATCH function for using it:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("plan";D2));"";D2)
```

Comment: thanks Dominique. After doing some more searching, I am looking for something like this:=IFERROR(INDEX($L2:$AQ2,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("POL",$L2:$AQ2)),COLUMN($A$2:$AH$2)-ROW(A$1)+1),COLUMN(A$1))),"")

Comment: thanks Dominique. After doing some more searching, I am looking for something like this:`=IFERROR(INDEX($L2:$AQ2,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("POL",$L2:$AQ2)),COLUMN($A$2:$AH$2)-ROW(A$1)+1),COLUMN(A$1))),"")` This seems to return what I need in the columns I want, but now trying to figure out how to convert this for multiple criteria. For instance, if more data columns are added and I needed to check for either "Adv" or "Rout" that may be in those additional columns, how do I incorporate the "OR" in the if(isnumber(search portion of this formula.